# echo ignores flag in child_process.exec()

Tags: node.js

When I type `echo -n foo` directly in bash, it works as expected and prints `foo` without any trailing new lines.

But, I've written the following code to print some text using child_process.exec() method;

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("echo -n foo",
    function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
);
```

However, the `-n` flag doesn't work as expected and it prints `-n foo` followed by a blank line.

**UPDATE:** I figured out that problem occurs only on OS X, I've tried the same script on Ubuntu and it works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works fine for me with at least node v0.10.30 on Linux.

This:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('echo -n foo', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.dir(stdout);
});
```

outputs:

```
'foo'
```

However, on Windows the behavior you describe does exist, but that is because Windows' `echo` command is not the same as on *nix (and so it echoes exactly what came after the command).

The reason it also does not work on OS X is because (from `man echo`):

```
     Some shells may provide a builtin echo command which is similar or iden-
     tical to this utility.  Most notably, the builtin echo in sh(1) does not
     accept the -n option.
```

When you call `exec()`, node spawns `/bin/sh -c "<command string>"` on *nix platforms. So (as noted in the man page) `/bin/sh` on OS X does not support `echo -n`, which results in the output you're seeing. However it works from the terminal because the default shell for that user is not `/bin/sh` but likely `/bin/bash`, which *does* support `echo -n`. It also works on Linux because most systems have `/bin/sh` pointing to `/bin/bash` or some other shell that supports `echo -n`.

So the solution is to change the command to force the use of the `echo` binary instead of the built-in shell's `echo`:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('`which echo` -n foo', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.dir(stdout);
});
```

or use [`spawn()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) like this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    p = spawn('echo', ['-n', 'foo']),
    stdout = '';
p.stdout.on('data', function(d) { stdout += d; });
p.stderr.resume();
p.on('close', function() {
  console.dir(stdout);
});
```

or if you want to keep using `exec()` without changing the code, then make `/bin/sh` a symlink to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Yes, it worked on Linux, it seems problem only occurs in OS X. I still couldn't get it work.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include information about behavior on OS X.

Answer (score -1):

The JavaScript `console.log` function appends a `\n` newline character to a string. If you want to print a string without a newline character, you can do it like this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("echo -n foo",
    function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        process.stdout.write(stdout);
    }
);
```

Comment: It's not the problem that `console.log()` is appending a new line. `echo -n` is appending a new line when called inside `child_process.exec()`. And when I `console.log()` the result, that outputs 2 new lines at the end. But as I just updated the question, it seems problem only occurs in OS X, not in Linux systems.

Comment: @EmreKayan oh okay, thanks for the clarification. Glad to see you got the problem fixed.